# JSF reading dynamic input element in a managed bean

Tags: html, forms, jsf

I have a pretty complex JSF page (we use JSF2 with facelet) in which I have to "plug-in" a pure html form section (it represents a WYSIWYG template for an document that will be created as Pdf later).
Very simplified the page looks like

```
<h:form id="formEditDoc">
   <p:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" value="Save"
      actionListener="#{myBean.myAction}" update="masterForm:msg">
   </p:commandButton>

   <!-- some jsf controls here -->
   ....

   <!-- this is my dynamic section -->
   <input id="ft2" type="text" value="foo"/>
</h:form>
```

In the managed bean myBean (request scoped) I have the action listener in which I try to get the "foo" string in this way:

```
String text1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("ft2");
```

But I can't get the value. Text1 is always null. I even tried to set ajax=false to the commandButton, but nothing changed.
Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the input's `name=value` pair which get sent as request parameter `name=value`, not the `id=value`. You need to set the `name` attribute instead.

```
<input id="ft2" name="ft2" type="text" value="foo"/>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I suggest to use `@ManagedProperty` instead to set the value:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.ft2}")
private String ft2;
```

Comment: First things first: thank you for the solution. For the general approach, my problem is more complicated. I can't use the @ManagedProperty("#{param.ft2}") private String ft2; technique because I don't know how many input field I'll have on my page: they depend's on some template the user can create themselves. For the same reason, I can't use the inputHidden: first I want the input box to be visible and ediable from the user, second I don't know how many of them I'm gonna need.

Comment: Give those inputs all the **same** name and use `#{paramValues.ft}` on a `String[]` property. They'll appear in order as they appeared in HTML DOM. Sorry about inputhidden, that was a silly suggestion, I overlooked that you didn't use `type="hidden"`.