# JSF managed property for multivalues

Tags: jsf, annotations, managed-bean

As suggested by BalusC as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8050061/333223), I wanto to create a managed property like this:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{paramValues.freetext}")
private String[] ftValues;

public String[] getFtValues(){ 
    return ftValues;
}

public void setFtValues(String[] values){
    ftValues = values;
}
```

In my project every managed bean declaration and settings has done in the faces-config.xml file. Putting the annotation in the code as suggested, doesn't bring me any result.
ftValues is always null, even if I have one or more `<input name="freetext">`
Is it possible that the annotation is not take into consideration because the main configuration technique use the XML file?

How can I put the ManagedProperty declaration into the `faces-config.xml`? I tried adding

```
<managed-property>
    <property-name>ftValues</property-name>
    <property-class>java.lang.String[]</property-class>
    <value>#{paramValues.freetext}</value>
</managed-property>
```

in the appropriate managed bean section, but it crashes with this error

> Bean or property class java.lang.String[] for managed bean myBean cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the annotations are ignored whenever you declare the bean in `faces-config.xml`. If removing the bean from `faces-config.xml` is really not an option for some unclear reason, then you need to remove the `<property-class>` to fix the problem. JSF can perfectly figure it by itself.